# Push data from WFFM to SalesForce

Tags: sitecore, salesforce

We are working on creating custom action to submit the data to SalesForce from WFFM. Has someone used SalesForce API or someother way to submit the data from WFFM to SalesForce?

Comment: It should be easy enough to do a simple call to SF in a Save Action using the web service that Salesforce provide. If you want a more fully featured solution and a product S4S provide a module for Salesforce integration. http://www.fuseit.com/products/sitecore-salesforce-integration/

Comment: Thanks. It is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three modules available that do what you're looking for.

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/SearchResults#qr=salesforce